# Include nested of nested child with LINQ

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to include the properties of a child property, but is returned as null, even I using inclusion for the property

```
 var notas =
                dtx.NFeItem.Where(n => n.Empresa.EmpresaId == empresa.EmpresaId)
                    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year >= anoInicial)
                    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month >= mesInicial)
                    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year <= anoFinal)
                    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month <= mesFinal)
                    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_tpNF == "1")
                    .Include(n => n.NFe)
                    .Include(n => n.NFe.participante.Empresa)
                    .GroupBy(g => new { g.CST_ICMS, g.CFOP, g.aliqICMS, g.pRedBC_ICMS, g.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month, g.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year, g.NFe.participante })
                    .Select(i => new { i.Key.CFOP, CST = i.Key.CST_ICMS, pICMS = i.Key.aliqICMS, pRedBC = i.Key.pRedBC_ICMS, mes = i.Key.Month, ano = i.Key.Year, NFePart = i.Key.participante });
```

Even using `Include(n => n.NFe.participante.Empresa)` the property returns null

Then I do the fall

```
 var periodos = notas.DistinctBy(i => new { i.ano, i.mes }).Select(i => new { i.ano, i.mes }).ToList();


            foreach (var periodo in periodos)
            {

                var notasPeriodo = notas.Where(i => i.ano == periodo.ano && i.mes == periodo.mes).ToList();
                var participantes = notasPeriodo.DistinctBy(p => p.NFePart.CNPJ).Select(i => i.NFePart).ToList();


    //etc.....
    }
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: EF is known to ignore includes when the query is using projection (select) like yours.

Comment: @IvanStoev you know how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF ignores the `Include` expressions if the final query result element type is not the entity used as root for the includes.

What you can do is to include the desired properties in the query projection and rely on EF navigation property fixup to bind them to the respective objects referencing them:

```
var notas = dtx.NFeItem
    .Where(n => n.Empresa.EmpresaId == empresa.EmpresaId)
    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year >= anoInicial)
    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month >= mesInicial)
    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year <= anoFinal)
    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month <= mesFinal)
    .Where(n => n.NFe.ide_tpNF == "1")
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.CST_ICMS, g.CFOP, g.aliqICMS, g.pRedBC_ICMS, g.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Month, g.NFe.ide_dEmi.Value.Year, g.NFe.participante })
    .Select(i => new
    { 
        i.Key.CFOP,
        CST = i.Key.CST_ICMS,
        pICMS = i.Key.aliqICMS,
        pRedBC = i.Key.pRedBC_ICMS,
        mes = i.Key.Month,
        ano = i.Key.Year,
        NFePart = i.Key.participante,
        // include properties:
        i.Key.participante.Empresa,
    });
```